# Azure Databricks to eventhub: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.TimeoutException

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub

Please help me to fix this issue. I am writing data to event hub from data-bricks(pyspark) streaming query as below:

```py
def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
  df.orderBy("_commit_timestamp")
  df.select(to_json(struct("*")).alias("body")).
    write.format("eventhubs").options(**ehConf).save()
                  
w_hubble_account_df = hubble_account_df.writeStream\
  .option("checkpointLocation", hubble_account_checkpoint_location)\
  .foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function).start()

w_hubble_account_df.awaitTermination()
```

This runs for few minutes and writes few thousands records to event hub successfully and then throws the TimeoutException. This is suppose to run continuously until stopped explicitly. What could be the possible root cause?

Comment: Behavior is so inconsistent. write-stream ran for 18 hours and stopped. Now when I rerun it  fails  in every 4 minutes.

Comment: I had the same problem as Akhilesh, and solved by working with this parameters on options(**ehWriteConf): eventhubs.operationTimeout and eventhubs.receiverTimeout

Check: https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/PySpark/structured-streaming-pyspark.md

They say operationTimeout is for writing, but without setting receiverTimeout wasn't working for me and took me a while to just try it, so hope it helps someone